# Why new lines at the end of files?

Tags: carriage-return

Why do some of the more technical apps require newlines at the end of files?  I've read it has something to do with diffs, but shouldn't diff be able to figure the relative positions of things out on its own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Text file are composed of text lines, which are *terminated* with newlines (as opposed to being *separated* by newlines). So omitting the last newline technically makes the last line an incomplete text line.

Answer (score 5):

I think it has more to do with appending to the end of the file. The convention is to have a newline at the end so that anything adding to the file doesn't have to worry about whether they need to make a break between the old content and the new.